# Calling method in my store returns empty observer object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am new with Vue.

I have a Vue component like below. The return value of my function `getBuildingsByOwnerRequest` is unexpected: It returns an empty observer object. Only if I run `getBuildingsByOwnerRequest` again I receive the expected output from my store action.

Could this be a reactivity problem?

```
data() {
    return {
        editedOwner = {
            "owner_id": 12223,
        }
    },
}

computed: {
    ...mapState("buildings", ["buildings_by_owner"]),
},

methods: {
    ...mapActions("buildings", ["getBuildingsByOwnerRequest"]),
   
    function() {
        this.getBuildingsByOwnerRequest(this.editedOwner.owner_id);
        console.log(this.buildings_by_owner) // returns empty observer object ([__ob__: Observer] with length: 0)

        // if I run the function again I get the expected return
    };
}
```

buildings.js (store):

```
state: {
    buildings_by_owner: []
},

actions: {
    getBuildingsByOwnerRequest({ dispatch }, owner_id) {
    axios
        .get(
            `${process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL}/get/buildings_by_owner/owner_id=${owner_id}`
        )
        .then((res) => {
            // API call returns valid json as expected
            dispatch("receiveBuildingsByOwner", res.data);
        });
    },

    receiveBuildingsByOwner({ commit }, payload) {
      commit("RECEIVED_BUILDINGS_BY_OWNER", payload);
    },
}

mutations: {
    RECEIVED_BUILDINGS_BY_OWNER(state, payload) {
      state.buildings_by_owner = payload;
    },
}
```

Comment: It's empty at the time when you call console.log (shouldn't be the first choice for debugging also). You don't return a promise from the action and don't chain it

Comment: Thank you for reaching out! This comment already gives me a clue. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about async to derive a full solution from your answer. Could you elaborate on how to return a promise in this specific case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is empty at the time it's logged. All asynchronous actions should return a promise:

```
getBuildingsByOwnerRequest({ dispatch }, owner_id) {
  return axios
  ...
```

A promise needs to be awaited before accessing results that it promises:

```
 this.getBuildingsByOwnerRequest(this.editedOwner.owner_id).then(() => {
   console.log(this.buildings_by_owner)
 })
```